# Get the download link of file on remote server as a property in json response web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, iis-7, asp.net-web-api2

I have uploaded files using web app made with asp.net web mvc, using **Server.MapPath()** and all that. Now its on remote server. 
All i want its **http download url** so that i can send this link via json and users on mobile can download that file? 
Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7.

[Link to Image of Json Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uSil.png)
**FilePath** property should have file download link but right now its giving me physical path of file where it is located on hard drive. Any thoughts on how to get download url?

Comment: Is Server.MapPath creating that FilePath?

Comment: Yes. I tried  **HostingEnvironment** class too.

Comment: @Jeff show your code!

Comment: @Div Did you mean to direct that at zubics?

Comment: @Div it's not my question, I was only asking a clarifying question